# verify if element exists, if not create the element once

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, i'm trying to figure out if a div exists before I create one using the function **create_modal()**.

Doing some research here, I came up with this simple code:

```
    ...

    var name = "modalAuthorWork";

    var modalwnd = $(name);

    # create the modal once
    if ( !modalwnd.length ) {
        create_modal(name);
    }
```

Here's the problem, the function **create_modal()** executes all the time. I know for a fact that the function does indeed create the new div, so that part works ok. So, i guess it does not check correctly if the div exists in the first place...

How do i fix this simple code?

Comment: That selector `modalAuthorWork` doesn't make much sense

Comment: are you sure is your name  a correct selector ? maybe should be #modalAuthorWork or . modalAuthorWork ?

Comment: No need to give negative votes to my question. I'm doing my best...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not checking for a div. You're checking for a literal DOM element whose tag name is `<modalAuthorWork>`.

if you want to check for an ID or css class of that name, it should be

```
 $('div#modalAuthorWork') // div  with ID modalAuthorWork
 $('div.modalAuthorWork') // div with css class modalAuthorWork
```

instead.